# Swift: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error access to keys on a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

Playground, Xcode 9.4.1

```
let openersToClosers: [Character: Character] = ["(": ")","[": "]","{": "}"]
print("openersToClosers.keys : \(openersToClosers.keys)")

let keys = openersToClosers.keys
print("keys : \(keys)")
```

I'm getting an error:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. It crashes in  a Playground, but not in a compiled project.

Comment: It happens only if the Key type is Character.